# use more than 4GB on GA-G31MF-S2

Tags: windows-7, memory

Anyone managed to use more than 4GB on a [GA-G31MF-S2](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2756#sp) motherboard?

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The board only supports 4GB. This is written on the Gigabyte page:

> 4 x 1.8V DDR2 DIMM sockets **supporting up to 4 GB of system memory**

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets) also shows that the G31 chipset only supports 4GB.